# Si cambio el cotejamiento a una base de datos mysql no se pierde ningún dato?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

cómo están? Les planteo mi duda. Tengo una BD en mysql ti tiene un cotejamiento latin, me está trayendo problemas al mostrar datos con caracteres especiales. Quería saber si no hay peligro con la integridad de los datos si cambio el cotejamiento a la BD ya cargada

Gracias!.

Comment: ¿Estás seguro que el cojetamiento es lo que buscas cambiar?, el cojetamiento solo da las reglas para comparar strings. El cambiar cojetamiento no altera en nada la BD salvo la forma en que se comparan los strings. A mi parecer lo que tu buscas es cambiar el conjunto de caracateres (characters set). El cambiar el characters set sí altera la BD dependiendo el gestor de base de datos. En el caso de mysql éste no modifica la BD sólo cambia la reinterpretación de los strings.

Comment: El problema es que la BD no la creé yo, quién la hizo le dejó un cotejamiento latin1_swedish. Yo necesito mostrar datos de las tablas que están en ella y cuando lo hago, los carácteres especiales me los muestra así �, intenté solcuionarlo con html y con php y no lo logré. Que me recomendarías hacer? Solo quiero que al mostrar los datos de las tablas, usando PHP los caracteres especiales aparezcan como son.

Comment: Hablemos por [el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71189/discussion-between-eduen-sarceno-and-jose-miguel-vina)

Comment: José, si no recuerdo mal, `latin1_swedish` no daría problemas con los acentos hasta el punto de mostrarte el carácter inspector en sustitución de los acentos. No obstante, si es una base de datos en castellano, lo mejor sería cambiarlo a `utf8_spanish_ci`. Hace un tiempo creé una BD y estaba en producción, tenía `latin1_swedish`, porque al crearla no me fijé en eso y fue lo que mysql asignó por defecto. Al cabo de un tiempo la cambié a `utf8_spanish_ci` y no hubo ningún problema. Revisa los datos que te aparecen extraños directamente en la BD y ...

Comment: .. si allí salen bien, significa que el problema está en otra parte (revisa al respecto [la respuesta a esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/59510/29967). Si salen mal directamente en la BD, puede que estuvieran mal codificados ya en la fuente de la cual fueron tomados los datos para insertarlos en la BD (archivo de texto, documento HTML sin codificación adecuada, etc).

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda. Descubrí que no es un problema de cotejamiento en la BD sino un problema con el hosting como tal. La web está alojada en hostgator.

Uso el mismo código en xampp en mi pc y muestra los caractres especiales, en cambio en el hosting no.